# Spring webflow second popup problem

Tags: popup, spring-webflow

I have 1st popup, and this 1st popup opens 2nd popup

Code:

```
<view-state id="paneMaintenance" parent="#pe-cards"  model="model">               
    <transition on="task-view" then="developers-task-view" bind="false">                    
    </transition>      
</view-state>




<view-state id="developers-task-view" view="/WEB-INF/jsp/taskView/taskAssignDevelopersPopUp.jsp" model="taskAssignModel" parent="#paneMaintenance" popup="true" >
    <transition on="create" to="create-task-after" bind="false" >
        <evaluate expression="taskAssignHandler.create(taskAssignModel, model.paneModel, true)" />
    </transition>
</view-state>


<view-state id="create-task-after" view="/WEB-INF/jsp/taskView/taskCreateAfter.jsp" model="taskAssignModel" parent="#developers-task-view" popup="true">
      <transition on="confirm" bind="true">
                 <evaluate expression="taskAssignHandler.saveTaskAssign(taskAssignModel, model.paneModel)" />
      </transition>
    <transition on="cancel" bind="false"  to="paneMaintenance"/>
</view-state>
```

I need to execute some code, then close 2nd popup, and then return to 1st popup.
How can i do it?
If 1st popup opens 2nd popup, and there is transition from 2nd popup to 1st popup, then 2nd popup opens second 1st popup, instead of close himself and return to 1st popup

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tiles and create some tiles definitions, like this:

```
<definition name="myBasicView" extends="myView">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/taskView/yourPageBody.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="myFirstView" extends="myView">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/taskView/yourPageBody.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="popup" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/taskView/taskAssignDevelopersPopUp.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="mySecondView" extends="myView">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/taskView/yourPageBody.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="popup" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/taskView/taskCreateAfter.jsp" />
</definition>
```

and then use these definitions:

```
<view-state id="paneMaintenance" parent="#pe-cards" model="model" view="myBasicView" >               
    <transition on="task-view" then="developers-task-view" bind="false">                    
    </transition>      
</view-state>

<view-state id="developers-task-view" view="myFirstView" model="taskAssignModel" parent="#paneMaintenance" popup="true" >
    <transition on="create" to="create-task-after" bind="false" >
        <evaluate expression="taskAssignHandler.create(taskAssignModel, model.paneModel, true)" />
    </transition>
</view-state>

<view-state id="create-task-after" view="mySecondView" model="taskAssignModel" parent="#developers-task-view" popup="true">
    <transition on="confirm" bind="true">
        <evaluate expression="taskAssignHandler.saveTaskAssign(taskAssignModel, model.paneModel)" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="cancel" bind="false" to="paneMaintenance"/>
</view-state>
```

So 1 popup for each view!